# Javascript: how to add < as text of label html

Tags: javascript, html

I have a label, and i change the text in this label using this code:

```
let label = document.getElementById("resultLabel")
label.innerHTML = stringResult;
```

where `stringResult` is a string.

It works, but if the string contains "<" the text is truncated at that point: for example if the string is "a<b" only "a" will be shown.

How can I insert a string containing "<" as the text of an HTML label?

Comment: Use `.textContent` instead of `.innerHTML` or encode it properly `&lt;` before adding it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript:output symbols and special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39291156/javascriptoutput-symbols-and-special-characters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using `.textContent`?

```
let label = document.getElementById("resultLabel");
label.textContent = stringResult;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can encode it with `&lt;`  like this :

```
a&lt;b
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape it `\<`.

```js
let label = document.getElementById("resultLabel")
label.innerHTML = 'a \< b';
```

```html
<label id='resultLabel'></label>
```